# Issue with variable heights

Tags: html, css-float, height

While modifying a phpBB forum, we need to create a custom topic/posts view.

Please see the image below for details 
[image]
The real problem is Partitions 1 and 2.

The code am using is [updated code](https://gist.github.com/vajrasar/6256861)

The result is -

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using, `#position1 {height: 100%;}` and for position 2 you can use `#position2 {height: 80%}` and for the no-scroll thing you can use `position{ overflow: none;}` this will tell the browser to no to create a scroll bar for this div!

Comment: yes am doing that. If am putting that right. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Than why not place it to the right? The code you are showing is having the float: left;

Comment: when I do float:right on partition 3 or even on partition 2 as well, this is what happens -> http://i.imgur.com/dZQm5dD.jpg?1?5177

Comment: Have you tried using `#position1 {float:left; height: 100%;}` and for the rest of two divs, combine them up in one div as `<div class="pos_two_three"></div>`and give this one css properties of `.pos_two_three{float: right; height: 100%}` now when you will provide other two divs different width. It will work!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I changed the code [ https://gist.github.com/vajrasar/6256861 ] as you pointed but still the partition 1 is not touching the bottom of the main container. [ http://i.imgur.com/Pl9Hu0N.png?1 ]

Comment: As you can see, there is a padding of 1px under it. What I have tried for the errr is something like: `position: fixed;` Also I have added 100% height. Now the banner to the left was moving no more! It was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

what ever you set your CSS just add javascript code @ the end of your file like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var h1=document.getElementById('div1').offsetHeight;
var h2=document.getElementById('div2').offsetHeight;
var h3=document.getElementById('div3').offsetHeight;
var h4=parseInt(h2)+parseInt(h3)+"px";

document.getElementById('div1').style.height=h4;
</script>
```

i run this code, it work for me.

Comment: I was thinking if there was any sole-CSS way to achieve this!